# Trying to Add different logo to my page

Tags: php, css, wordpress, html

I have a theme that I am customizing on WordPress (Increate themes). The thing is that the owner wants a page that talks about something different and it will also have a different logo for this particular page.

My question is: How can I insert a different logo in this page?

I already have a logo in all my webpages, but I want to have 2 different logos:
One for a particular page and another for all the other pages.

This is my theme `header.php`:

```
<div class="headdown <?php echo $sticky_header;?>">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="logo">
            <a title="<?php bloginfo("description");?>" href="<?php echo home_url();?>">
                <?php if ($ht_options['logo_url']) { ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $ht_options['logo_url'];?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>"/>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <img  src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/images/logo.png" alt="Logo"/>

                <?php }?>

            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: @praveen Kumar, Thanks for the edit. Please can you help me out with this? I am really stuck.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the notification. What theme are you editing? Where can I have a look? More information please?

Comment: i am editing increate theme (http://demo.highthemes.com/increate/) but i am working on my local wamp. @PraveenKumar

Comment: It's not a free theme I guess. So is it possible to see it online?

Comment: Yes @PraveenKumar i sent you the demo link

Comment: Yea, if that's gonna be a commercial version, how can I use?

Comment: i am working on it on my local server, thats why i copied the header.php logo part on my question

Comment: Right... `header.php` is the right file. But what about the documentation.

Comment: should i show you the whole header.php code? i can do that

Comment: That would be too much buddy... :(

Comment: Well since it's wordpress theme there should be some admin panel where you can change logo. If there is no such thing create child theme and modify header.php. You can also use jQuery to resend url :) If you want i can post code for that. If you send codepen or whatever with header.php i can tell you which line it is.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec yes i already have a logo in my webpages but i want to have 2 different logo, one for a particular page and another for the rest pages.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec the answer Ravi Patel gave was for the same answer you gave me, although i didnt validate it previously because i didnt use his code, but i thanked him. I validated him recently because you mentioned his answer was correct. If you wish not to help me again its no problem, I really appreciate your time and also for the help. Its well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Use [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-post-thumbnails/) for add image as logo(same like Featured thumbnails). And called based on post id.

Add this code on function.php

```
/*Logo Image*/
if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) {
    //$types = array('post', 'page');
    $types = array('page');
    foreach($types as $type) {
        new MultiPostThumbnails(array(
            'label' => 'Header Banner',
            'id' => 'secondary-image',
            'post_type' => $type
            )
        );
    }
}
```

**call this value on header.php**

```
$value = MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_url(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image');
```

2) Create custom options for media select and call meta value on header.